# Display Sort by option on Top and Pagination at bottom

Tags: toolbar, pager

On my product listing page, I need to change the display of Toolbar and Pager.

On top, I want to display **Sort by** option while on bottom I need to display **Pagination**

How can I achieve this ?

Please Guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

One way of solving your issue is by hiding and showing toolbar HTML elements

For **top** toolbar your CSS should look like the following:

```
.toolbar .pager {
    display: none;
}
```

For **bottom** toolbar your CSS should look like the following:

```
.toolbar-bottom .toolbar .pager {
    display: block;
}

.toolbar-bottom .toolbar .sorter {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Another solution is to create a new toolbar template file for bottom and keep pager code and remove sort code and then call toolbar bottom template in product listing. Follow the following steps to accomplish this solution:

- Copy `toolbar.phtml` from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` to your custom theme template `app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_template/product/list/toolbar.phtml`
- Make a copy of `toolbar.phtml` and name it `toolbar-bottom.phtml`
- Edit `toolbar.phtml` and remove pager code
- Edit `toolbar-bottom.phtml` and remove sort code
- Copy `list.phtml` from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_template/catalog/product/list.phtml`
- Edit `list.phtml` and replace the following code:

Existing code:

```
<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

With this code:

```
<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. The CSS solution will work for sure but while the page is still being loaded the pager/sorter can be seen. Also the **toolbar-bottom.phtml** solution do not work for me. I am usign version 1.7