# How to separate toolbar.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.7, parent-child-theme

In product listing page (catalog/product/list.phtml) the **toolbar.phtml** is getting called, which is for **two things**.

1. For **sorting** option
2. For **pagination**

For pagination I have called `$this->getPagerHtml()` in the toolbar.phtml.
I want to display the **sorting option before the product list** (i.e. top) and the **pagination in the bottom** of the list.
So **how to divide** it in proper way so that I can call it at any location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this using css.
I took a parent div and then put the sorter div and pagination div inside it.
Then By using the parent and child div class I just hide the div where necessary and show where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

find the bellow link this will help you.

[Display Sort by option on Top and Pagination at bottom](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19137/display-sort-by-option-on-top-and-pagination-at-bottom)

> You can achieve via css.
>
> or another option is to get via new template

please see above link.

**I hope this will help you.**